# Energy loss through resistors in series

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I am trying to understand some A level electricity basics. Unfortunately I stumbled upon a concept that does not seem intuitive to me; this concept goes as follows: for some resistance a charge loses all of its energy when flowing through it, but if we have two of these resistances in series the same charge would only lose half of its energy when going through each one of them.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please make a descriptive title for your question

Comment: N.B. 'A' levels are exams taken in the UK usually at age 18. ('A' for advanced).

Answer (score 1):

> . . . . . a charge loses all of its energy when flowing through it . . . . . . .

Whilst passing through a resistor a mobile charge loses as much energy as it gains.

The drift speed of the mobile charges through a resistor is constant ie there is no net gain or loss of kinetic energy.

Inside the resistor there is an electric field generated by a battery.

The electric field accelerates the mobile charges, ie they gain kinetic energy at the expense of electric potential energy, between collisions with the lattice ions.
On "colliding" with the lattice ions the mobile charges lose kinetic energy and the lattice ions gain that energy.
There is a continuous process of the mobile charges gaining kinetic energy and then losing kinetic energy as they pass through a resistor.

If you have two resistors in series then with the potential difference across them the same as when there was just one resistor the electric field is now halved from its value with one resistor.

Because the electric field is smaller the mobile charge carriers now gain less kinetic energy between collisions with the lattice ions and hence lose less kinetic energy when they collide with the lattice ions, but again the rate of gain is equal to the rate of loss.
The drift speed of the mobile charge carriers is also smaller than that when only one resistor was present which is equivalent to saying that the current through two resistors in series is smaller than the current for just one resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the amount of energy the charge starts and ends with don't depend on the resistor, they depend (typically) on the power supply (or voltage source or other source) you use to put the charge onto one of the resistor's terminals, and take it off the other terminal.

Comment: I think you mean "the amount of energy the charge starts with...", don't you?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez, yes, thanks.